# Local date with PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, date, local

I'd like to echo the current local date (not the server date) using PHP and JavaScript.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php

$year = '<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    document.write(year);
    </script>';

$month = '<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var monthName = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "november", "December");
    var curMonth = monthName[month];
    document.write(curMonth);
    </script>';

$day='<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDate();
    document.write(day);
    </script>';

$curDateString = $day . " " . $month . " " . $year;
$curDate = date('m/d/y', strtotime($curDateString));
echo $curDate;

?>
```

It always returns `01/01/70`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are mixing JavaScript and PHP. PHP will be interpreted at the server and JavaScript will be interpreted at the client, so there is no possibility to give values from JavaScript to PHP in that way. Do you want the local date of the client or of the server? As PHP will be run on the server it is only possible to get the date of the server, whereas JavaScript only can determine the date of the client.

Comment: You can't mix client-side and server-side code.

Comment: Did you ever check your variables `$day, $year, $month`, there is nothing.

Comment: If I check $curDateString it gets 1 November 2013 so I thoudht it would be work. So there is no way to get the client date using php and javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code will be executed on the client-side, not server-side. It means the JavaScript code will not get evaluated on the server-side, and therefore the string `$curDateString` won't have the value you think it does.

A normal `echo $curDateString` or `var_dump($curDateString)` will output `3 november 2013` -- this is because the default `Content-Type` is `text/html`. The code inside the `$curDateString` variable will get executed on the client-side and the output will be `3 november 2013`.

To understand what `$curDateString` really contains, you can do the following:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
var_dump($curDateString);
```

This will output something like below:

```
string(587) "<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date();
    ...
    </script>
```

To PHP, this is random gibberish. You then use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) on the above string but it fails and will return `01/01/70` as the output.

To achieve what you want, you can make an [AJAX call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which would pass the date values from the client-side. You can then receive this input in your PHP script, process it server-side and send back the accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple using `PHP only` :

For example if you are from London you would do :

`date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');`

After that you would get the time:

`$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a');`

`echo $date`